# Counting a sequence in a string C language

Tags: c, string, sequence

I'm trying to write a function that gets two strings, a short string called str1, and a longer one called str2.

the function will count how many times is str1 found in str2.

```
example: str1= 'ab' str2 = 'abab' print 2
```

but for some reason, for the above example. i get 3. This is my code:

```
    int how_many_times(char* str1,char* str2)
{
    int result=0,i,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str2);i++)
    {
        if((str1[i]==str2[j]))
        {
            while(str1[i]==str2[j])
            {
                j++;
                if(j==strlen(str1))
                {
                    result++;
                    j=0;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    printf("%d",result);
    getch();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can use [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) for that.

Comment: You are messing up your indices. With these short inputs, you can just write down the values of i, j and what they point to. You will find that you increase i way too often, and that you increase result before you have actually checked that the string matches (j points to 'b', but i doesn't point to the corresponding character in str2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is likely a learning exercise, I would not suggest using a library function, assuming that you would rather fix your code.

Your code is close to working:

- **You swapped `i` and `j` in the code that accesses `str[...]`** - you need to access `str1` with `j` and `str2` with `i`, not the other way around, because `i` goes up to `strlen(str2)` and `j` goes up to `strlen(str1)`
- **You need to reset `j` to zero when you find a mismatch** - The `else` branch of the `if` needs to reset `j` after a partial match has been found.

Here is [your modified code running on ideone](http://ideone.com/7GxLav).

```
int how_many_times(char* str1,char* str2)
{
    int result=0,i,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str2);i++)
    {
        if((str1[j]==str2[i])) // <<<=== Swapped i and j
        {
            while(str1[j]==str2[i]) // <<<=== Swapped i and j
            {
                j++;
                if(j==strlen(str1))
                {
                    result++;
                    j=0;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        else {
            i++;
            j = 0; // <<<=== Added
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

P.S. Library-based solution is better :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I wanted. Was driving me crazy. Turns out i switched i and j...I would have never found that out ^^ Thanks. It's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 3):

```
int count(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *p;
    int c;

    c = 0;
    for (p = strstr(s2, s1); p; p = strstr(p, s1)) {
        c++;
        p++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of a string within another. We can use this to count the number of occurrences by incrementing a variable `count` until the function returns NULL.

```
int countOccur(char *a, char *b) {
  int count = 0;
  while (b = strstr(b, a)) {
    count++;
    b++;
  }

  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this (doesn't use strstr, but does use strlen):

```
int how_many_times(char *str, char *str2) {
    int result = 0, i = 0, j, k, len = strlen(str);

    while(str2[i]) {
        j = 0;
        k = 0;

        while(1) {
            if(str[j + k] == str2[i + k] && str[j] != 0) {
                if(j + k == len - 1) {
                    result++;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
            k++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```